# Java compare strings from two places and exclude any matches

Tags: java, replace, while-loop, bufferedreader, stringbuffer

I'm trying to end up with a **results.txt** minus any matching items, having successfully compared some string inputs against another .txt file. Been staring at this code for way too long and I can't figure out why it isn't working. New to coding so would appreciate it if I could be steered in the right direction! Maybe I need a different approach? Apologies in advance for any loud tutting noises you may make. Using Java8.

```
//Sending a String[] into 'searchFile', contains around 8 small strings.
//Example of input: String[]{"name1","name2","name 3", "name 4.zip"}
                              ^ This is my exclusions list.

    public static void searchFile(String[] arr, String separator)
    {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if(i != 0) b.append(separator);
            b.append(arr[i]);
            String findME = arr[i];
            searchInfo(MyApp.getOptionsDir()+File.separator+"file-to-search.txt",findME);
        }
    }
```

^This works fine. I'm then sending the results to 'searchInfo' and trying to match and remove any duplicate (complete, not part) strings. This is where I am currently failing. Code runs but doesn't produce my desired output. It often finds part strings rather than complete ones. I think the 'results.txt' file is being overwritten each time...but I'm not sure tbh!

**file-to-search.txt** contains: "name2","name.zip","name 3.zip","name 4.zip" (text file is just a single line)

```
public static String searchInfo(String fileName, String findME)
{
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

        String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if(line.startsWith("\""+findME+"\""))
                 {
                    sb.append(line);
                        //tried various replace options with no joy
                        line = line.replaceFirst(findME+"?,", "");

                        //then goes off with results to create a txt file
                        FileHandling.createFile("results.txt",line);
                }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();        
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**What i'm trying to end up with is** a result file MINUS any matching complete strings (not part strings):

e.g. **results.txt** to end up with: "name.zip","name 3.zip"

Comment: What is `FileHandling`?

Comment: FileHandling.createFile just creates a text file for me based on two inputs, a fileName and the content.

Comment: am i correct in assuming that you have a file with a string on each line. You want a function which you provide the file to and a string. You want to create a new file with results in which if any of the line in the file you already had, matches with the string you provided, it should not be part of the new file. So if you had a file with 
123
456
756
and you provided 456 as a string, you want a new file that contains
123
756
please assume spaces as newlines as they're not showing correctly in comment :)

Comment: @masadwin. Hi, the file is just one line, with multiple strings e.g. "123", "456", 756". Or to put another way, when I open the file in a text editor only one line is displayed. The results file strings need to be on just one line also, as it'll be read by a 3rd party program that only reads line 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok with the information I have. What you can do is this

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");
for (String s : content.split(", ")) {
    if (!s.equals(findME)) { // assuming both have string quotes added already
        result.add(s);
    }
}
FileUtils.write(newFile, String.join(", ", result), "UTF-8");
```

using apache commons file utils for ease. You may add or remove spaces after comma as per your need.

Comment: Thanks. Trying this, it's currently coming up with: The method readFileToString(File, String) in the type FileUtils is not applicable for the arguments (String, String).

Comment: you want to pass a `File` object as the first parameter instead of string. Which IDE are you using? you should be getting hints as to what parameters a method may accept. You pass the string in the `File` constructor. Like `new java.io.File("pathToFile")`

Comment: I'm using Eclipse (Mars) on Windows. The message has moved onto: Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor. I'll keep looking. Regarding, the code I have above, is my presumption correct that my current results file might be overwritten each time do you know?

Comment: are you trying to write `new File()` in your `FileHandling` constructor?. the output file depends on what you pass in `newFile` in the last line. If you keep supplying the same path, then yes it will overwrite

Comment: Thanks, I added a random character generator to the filename earlier and saw 4 new files, one for each loop. Only want one file haha. Thanks for your help to date!

Comment: the write file method will come after loop, we are only adding the result to a list inside the loop.

Comment: I see that in your code. I was referring to my code. I wasn't sure whether the file was being overwritten but now I know :) Still trying to get your code working. The error messages have progressed again to: The method write(File, CharSequence, String) in the type FileUtils is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String) on the FileUtils.write line. Eclipse suggests to change to writeLines but that doesn't help either.

Comment: the first parameter of `FileUtils.write` method needs to be a `java.io.File` object. You can't pass a path directly. If your file path is 'c:/myfile.txt', you can do `FileUtils.write(new java.io.File("c:/myfile.txt"), String, String)`

Comment: Ticked your code solution as it was the most helpful in helping me find a solution. Cheers!